# Read an Array field from Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

I need some help with reading an array field within firebase. I can read string fields such as make and icon, however, when comes to the array which is under the same document am getting the result as null. Please find my FirebaseData as an attachment as well the code below. Am capturing the data that comes from firebase on the brands_screen this is where I expect to see the array data that comes from firebase.

Firebase Data
[FirebaseData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wssyW.png)
database API.dart.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class Api {
  final Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;
  final String path;
  CollectionReference ref;
  Api (this.path){
    ref = _db.collection(path);
  }
  Future<QuerySnapshot> getDataColletions(){
    return ref.getDocuments();
  }
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> streamDataCollection(){
    return ref.snapshots();
  }

  Future<DocumentSnapshot> getDocumentById(String id){
    return ref.document(id).get();
  }
  Future<DocumentSnapshot>removeDocumentById(String id){
    ref.document(id).delete();
  }
  Future<void> updateDocument(Map data, String id){
    return ref.document(id).updateData(data);
  }
  Future<DocumentReference>addDocument(Map data){
    return ref.add(data);
  }
}
```

brands_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gerente_loja/core/services/api.dart';
import 'package:gerente_loja/ui/screens/proforma_screen.dart';
import 'package:gerente_loja/ui/widgets/DropDownModel.dart';

class BrandsScreens extends StatelessWidget {

  String user;
  BrandsScreens(this.user);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List <String> models;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Selecionar o Carro '),
        //centerTitle: TextAlign.center,
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown[500],
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: [
            Text(user != '' ?  user.toUpperCase() : 'No Logged User'),
        ]
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: Api('vehicle').getDataColletions(),
            builder: (context, snapshot){
              if (!snapshot.hasData){
                return Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                        Colors.blueGrey),
                  ),
                );
              }
              else {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index){
                    return Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                      child: InkWell(
                        splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                        child: Card(
                          //color: Colors.blueGrey,
                          child: ListTile(
                            leading: AspectRatio(
                                aspectRatio: 0.8,
                                child: Image.network(
                                  snapshot.data.documents[index]['icon'],
                                  height: 500,
                                  //width: 300,
                                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                )
                            ),
                            title: Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]['make'],
                              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),
                            ),
                            onTap: (){
                              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
                                  ProformaScreen(snapshot.data.documents[index]['make']),
                                ),
                              );
                              models = snapshot.data['model'][index];
                              print(models[0]);
                              menuModel(models);
                            } ,
                          ),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueGrey),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              }
            }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

proforma_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:gerente_loja/ui/screens/signup_screen.dart';
import 'package:gerente_loja/ui/widgets/DropDownModel.dart';
import 'package:gerente_loja/ui/widgets/dropDown_Widget.dart';
import 'package:nice_button/NiceButton.dart';

import 'loginPage.dart';

class ProformaScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  //Text Fields Controllers.
  String carBrand;
  List<String> carModel;
  ProformaScreen(this.carBrand);

  @override
  _ProformaScreenState createState() => _ProformaScreenState(this.carBrand);

}
class _ProformaScreenState extends State<ProformaScreen> {
  String carBrand;
  List<String> carModel;

  _ProformaScreenState(this.carBrand);

  final _pecaController = TextEditingController();
  final _marcaController = TextEditingController();
  final _modelController = TextEditingController();
  final _yearController = TextEditingController();

  GlobalKey <FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var check;

  //LoginScreen(this.product);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List <String>carModel;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown[500],
        title: Text(
          "Proforma",
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        //Create an Action Which will be just a single button to stay on top right corner

      ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      body: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 80.0),
            child: Form(
              autovalidate: false,
              key: _formKey,
              child: ListView(
                //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                    ),
                    controller: _pecaController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.brown[500],
                        ),
                      ),
                      labelText: 'Nome da Peça',
                      hintText: 'Exmplo: ' + 'Pistões',
                      icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.tools,
                        color: Colors.brown[500],
                      ),
                    ),
                    //Open The Virtual KeyBoard on Phone
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    validator: (String val) {
                      if (val.isEmpty)
                        return "Por Favor, Escreva o Peça tipo Deseja ";
                      return null;
                    },
                    autofocus: true,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                  TextFormField(
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                    ),
                    controller: _marcaController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      fillColor: Colors.brown,
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                        ),
                      ),
                      //labelText: 'peca',
                      hintText: carBrand,
                      //Disable The text Box
                      enabled: false,
                      icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.car,
                          color: Colors.brown[500],
                      ),
                    ),
                    //Open The Virtual KeyBoard on Phone
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,

                    validator: (String val) {
                      if (val.isEmpty)
                        return "Por Favor, Escreva o Peça tipo Deseja ";
                      return null;
                    },
                    autofocus: true,

                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                  TextFormField(
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                    ),
                    controller: _modelController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                     // fillColor: Colors.white,
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.brown[500],
                        ),
                      ),
                      labelText: 'Modelo',
                      hintText: 'Exmplo: ' + 'Land Cruiser',
                      //Disable The text Box
                      icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.car,
                          color: Colors.brown[500],
                      ),
                    ),
                    //Open The Virtual KeyBoard on Phone
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,

                    validator: (String val) {
                      if (val.isEmpty)
                        return "Por Favor, Escreva o Peça tipo Deseja ";
                      return null;
                    },
                    autofocus: true,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 16.0),

                  Icon(Icons.calendar_today,
                      color: Colors.brown[300]
                  ),

                  menuYear(),
                  menuModel(carModel),

                  SizedBox(height: 25.0),
                  NiceButton(
                    width: 255,
                    elevation: 8.0,
                    radius: 52.0,
                    text: "Solicitar",
                    background: Colors.brown[500],
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    onPressed: () async {
                        String Response = await showDialog<String>(context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context){
                          return AlertDialog(
                            content: Text('Entrar, Cadastra-se ou Cancela Por favor !!!'),
                            actions: [
                              FlatButton(
                                child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.user,
                                color: Colors.brown[500],
                                ),
                                onPressed: (){
                                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>
                                      LoginPageScreen(),
                                  ));
                                },
                              ),
                              FlatButton(
                                child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.userPlus,
                                  color: Colors.brown[500],
                                ),
                                onPressed: (){
                                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>
                                  SignUpScreen()
                                  ));
                                },
                              ),
                              FlatButton(
                                child: Icon(Icons.close,
                                  color: Colors.brown[500] ,
                                ),
                                onPressed: (){
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                          }
                        );
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),

    );
  }
}
```

DropDownModel.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class menuModel extends StatefulWidget {
  List<String> carModel;
  menuModel(this.carModel);
  @override
  _menuModelState createState() => _menuModelState(this.carModel);
}

class _menuModelState extends State<menuModel> {
  List<String> carModel;
  _menuModelState(this.carModel);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String selectModel;
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 16.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0)
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0, right: 16.0),
        child: DropdownButton(
          hint: Text('Seleciona o Ano'),
          dropdownColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 5,
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
          isExpanded: true,
          iconSize: 36.0,
          value: selectModel,
          onChanged: (value){
            setState(() {
              selectModel = value;
            });
          },
          items: carModel.map((value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem (
              value: value,
              child:  Text(value),);
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you mean this `print(models[0]);` is null?

Comment: @PeterHaddad yes it does print null as if I was reading the data wrong. what gets me confused is the fact I can read the String fields from the firebase, but I cannot read the array field. I tried a different way to read still get same result. Only work around I found was to create a function in another class and call it where in I need in brand class here is the code of the function. 
```

Comment: try `print(snapshot.data.documents[index]['model'])`